# Optimize mongo $in query

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

I've a mongo collection having around 550,000 documents. Document has an array field `path` on which i have a below query in my java code. This field is indexed.

Problem is `ids` in below query can go up to 6000 causing the query to take ~8 secs. Tried to use aggregator to bring it down but no luck.

Could some one please guide here what else can be done.

```
Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("ancestors").is(null).and("path").in(ids));
var data = mongoTemplate.findDistinct(query, "path", Orders.class, String.class);
```

Comment: Can you tell us more about your actual use case? If `ids`' content will vary differently every time, I don't think it is a normal use case. The closest I can imagine is users selecting *all* values in a dropdown box; but in this case, you can just skip this selection criteria(i.e. just remove the `where` clause to select every value) or limit the selection size.

Comment: `ids` will vary as per the user. It is not a values from dropdown but ids from some other collections based on the access levels and will always be greater than 100.

Comment: Maybe you can put the selection indicator in the reference collection and perform `$lookup` to there like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/xBRSQfTwnvD)?

Answer (score 0):

When you use $in operator for find queries, after ~200 units, it converts the query to individual IO queries.
You should rather convert the usecase to range operator if they are in seq.

Ex:

```
ids.sort()
{ path: {gte: ids[0], lte: ids[n]} }
```

you can get a cursor with this filter and using next you can fetch records one by one.
this will not overload your system IO resources, you will get the data even faster without context switch as well.

If your ids are not in seq, then you can break that large req in multiple req of 100 batches and call them sequentially/parallely as per your usecase.

Comment: What are 'individual IO queries and how does that differ from what it does when fewer items are in the list?

Comment: when you have less than 200 items for $in filter operator it works as equality filter, but when it exceeds that it converts into range filter which will bring a lot more document in memory for mongo server.
you can read more about the difference here. https://www.alexbevi.com/blog/2020/05/16/optimizing-mongodb-compound-indexes-the-equality-sort-range-esr-rule/